# Mongodb refers in query

Tags: mongodb

I'm newbie in mongo, so:
I have a collection 'my_collection' like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a621"),
    "company_name" : "Microsoft",
    "type" : 'company',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a622"),
    "company_name" : "Google",
    "type" : 'company',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a623"),
    "company_name" : "Apple",
    "type" : 'company',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a624"),
    "name" : "John",
    "surname" : "Smith",
    "type" : 'person',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a625"),
    "name" : "Eugene",
    "surname" : "Harper",
    "type" : 'person',
    "company_id" : '5546329a470000850084a622',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a626"),
    "name" : "Philipp",
    "surname" : "Hoffman",
    "type" : 'person',
    "company_id" : '5546329a470000850084a622',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a627"),
    "name" : "Adam",
    "surname" : "Jonson",
    "type" : 'person',
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a628"),
    "name" : "Bruse",
    "surname" : "Willis",
    "type" : 'person',
    "company_id" : '5546329a470000850084a623',
}
```

I need to get a list of companies that have employees. (ie if an employee refers to a company, it must be listed)

I think in MySQL my query would be something like this:

```
SELECT * from my_collectionWHERE type = company AND (type = person AND company_id = _id)
```

So, in the result I expect two companies:
1. Google
2. Apple

What query it needed in mongo to get this result?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a621"),
    "company_name" : "Microsoft",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a622"),
    "company_name" : "Google",
}
```

It's wrong

```
$collection = $db -> my_collection->find(
  array(
    "type" => 'company',
    "_id" => { $in: [ 
        "type" => 'person',
        "_id" => ???,
      ]
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: You would need to covert your schema first so that you cast the string `company_id` to `ObjectId()`. Once that's done you can query using `$lookup` joining the same collection.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't convert schema, because It not my database, and it already very large. So it's impossible from my side.

Comment: You'll need to do it in two requests if you cant change the company_id type to ObjectId. First request to get all documents where type is company and second request to check if any entry exist in collection for type and company_id.

Answer (score 0):

Your both the ids are different. So you are using $in is perfect. I don't know much about php but $in query takes an array of argument as parameters.

So pass ["5546329a470000850084a621", "5546329a470000850084a622"] value in $in query.

Your code will be something like this:

```
$collection = $db -> my_collection->find(
  array(
    "type" => 'company',
    "_id" => { $in: ["5546329a470000850084a621", "5546329a470000850084a622"]
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: In my example it's possble to use 

      $in: ["5546329a470000850084a621", "5546329a470000850084a622"]

because it very small database. But actually I have very large database with hundreeds companies and thouthands persons. I can't simply list ids/

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible to convert the schema then you would need to run two queries; one to get the company ids for documents which have a person "type" with the result mapped to ObjectIds and the final to query the collection with the above ids.

Consider the following queries:

```
const company_ids = db.my_collection.distinct("company_id", 
    { "type": "person", "name": { "$exists": true } }
).map(ObjectId);
db.my_collection.find({ "_id": { "$in": company_ids } }, { "company_name": 1 });
```

---

For an effective query which leverages the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** operator that can do a self-join on the same collection, you need to change your schema first i.e. cast the `company_id` string to `ObjectId`.

A couple of ways you can go about the schema conversion. For relatively large collections use the **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)** method with batched updates as:

```
let bulkUpdateOps = [],
    cursor = db.my_collection.find({ "company_id": { "$type": 2 } });

cursor.forEach(doc => {
    const { _id, company_id } = doc;
    let temp = new ObjectId(company_id);

    bulkUpdateOps.push({
        "updateOne": {
           "filter": { _id },
           "update": { "$set": { company_id: temp } },
           "upsert": true
        }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
        db.my_collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);  
        bulkUpdateOps = [];                 
    }
}); 

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) {
    db.my_collection.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
}
```

or for small collections as straightforward as

```
db.my_collection.find({ "company_id": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(doc => {
    doc.company_id = new ObjectId(doc.company_id);
    db.test.save(doc);    
});
```

---

After the schema conversion, you can then query using the aggregation framework which has a **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)** pipeline step that you can use to create a "self-join" of the collection, a final **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** stage to query the companies with the employees and return the desired result.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "my_collection",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "company_id",
            "as": "employees"
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "employees.0": { "$exists": true } } }
])
```

Sample Output

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a622"),
    "company_name" : "Google",
    "type" : "company",
    "employees" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a625"),
            "name" : "Eugene",
            "surname" : "Harper",
            "type" : "person",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a622")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a626"),
            "name" : "Philipp",
            "surname" : "Hoffman",
            "type" : "person",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a622")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a623"),
    "company_name" : "Apple",
    "type" : "company",
    "employees" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a628"),
            "name" : "Bruse",
            "surname" : "Willis",
            "type" : "person",
            "company_id" : ObjectId("5546329a470000850084a623")
        }
    ]
}
```